# htaccess - Forward by path segment

Tags: .htaccess

I want to forward https://www.example.com/de/path/some/more/paths/ to http://sub.example.com/de/path/some/more/path/ by htaccess. The "some/more/paths" is a variable number of paths segments.

I tried with an RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/de/path/(.+) http://sub.example.com/de/path/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rule seems to be ignored - nothing happens.

Comment: Try remove the leading slash in rewrite rule.  `RewriteRule ^de/path/(.+)` in htaccess directory context there is no leading slash so it will never match.